# postgres update through php

Tags: php, postgresql

I am a complete novice at php and postgres. I have been searching all over the net for an answer but no joy! I have a postgres table called workorders. It has a primary key (ident). I am trying to up date it using a php script/program. Basically the ident is the workorder number. I have written a php script where i type in the workorder number, post it to another php file, which connects to the database, finds the ident that matches and updates it by adding 'paid' to a column called paid. I have made it work using INSERT into, but it will not allow duplicate keys so that is why i am trying to use update. When I do, it says "unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include('adodb5/adodb.inc.php');

$DB = &ADONewConnection('postgres');
$DB->PConnect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=secret');

if (!$DB) {
  die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}

$arr = array( array('paid',$_POST['$invoice']), );
$ok = $DB->Execute('insert into workorders (paid, ident) values (?,?)',$arr);

if (!$ok) {
  die("Invoice not posted. " . pg_last_error ());
}

?>
```

If I use this I can insert into my database. If I replace INSERT into with UPDATE or pg_update I get errors.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code which includes your SQL and the php call to execute that SQL?

Comment: (It sounds like you've got unmatched quote marks)

Comment: <?php
include('adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
 $DB = &ADONewConnection('postgres');
 $DB->PConnect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=secret');
 if (!$DB) {
     die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
 }       
$arr = array(

         array('paid',$_POST['$invoice']),

            );

$ok = $DB->Execute('insert into workorders (paid, ident) values (?,?)',$arr);
if (!$ok) {
 die("Invoice not posted. " . pg_last_error ());
}
    

 
?>

if I use this I can insert into my database. If I replace INSERT into with UPDATE or pg_update I get errors.

Comment: Sorry, thats all a bit cramped.

Comment: You should not post your code in the comments - edit your question and use the code formatting option there (indent by four spaces or highlight the code and press the '101010' button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have now seen your code, which looks fine.

T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING is often the result of not escaping quotation marks when used in strings.  But I am not seeing that here.  Can you post the example that does not work?

```
include('adodb5/adodb.inc.php');

$DB = &ADONewConnection('postgres');
$DB->PConnect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=secret');
if (!$DB) {
    die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}

$arr = array( array('paid',$_POST['$invoice']), );
$ok = $DB->Execute('insert into workorders (paid, ident) values (?,?)',$arr);
if (!$ok) {
    die("Invoice not posted. " . pg_last_error ());
}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
 <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>       

<form action="test.php" method="post">
      Enter invoice number to pay:<input type='text' name="$invoice" value=>
      <p>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Invoice">
    </form> 
 
   </body>
 </html>

Comment: this is the first form that asks me what invoice number i am wanting to pay

Comment: include('adodb5/adodb.inc.php');

$DB = &ADONewConnection('postgres');
$DB->PConnect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=secret');
if (!$DB) {
    die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}

$arr = array( array('paid',$_POST['$invoice']), );
$ok = $DB->Execute('update workorders (paid, ident) values (?,?)',$arr);
if (!$ok) {
    die("Invoice not posted. " . pg_last_error ());
}

Comment: this gives me and error of:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1: update workorders (paid, ident) values ( $1, $2) ^

Comment: UPDATE and INSERT statements do not look anything alike. Reading a basic course on SQL will be much helpful in your case. Start here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql.html and also here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dml.html, for you specific "problem".

Comment: Thank you Milen. That is what I was trying to find on the net but I could not find anything to point me in the right direction. Thanks for the links.